# The largest and smallest number wichout array

Tags: javascript

I got the task to enter numbers in the alert, and as the user enters 0 to display the largest and smallest number, I can not use arrays

```
i = 0;

while(true){
    ile = parseInt(prompt("Podaj liczbę"));   

    if(ile == 0)
        break;               

     //here i've a problem
     i++;

}

document.write("Max to: "+max+" Min to: "+min);
```

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Assuming this is a homework assignment or the like, given the "no arrays" constraint, so here's a hint:  you need to keep track of two numbers; the largest one entered so far, and the smallest one entered so far.  That implies you need two variables (besides the user input `ile`.)  You've already named those for your output; all you need is to set those variables correctly on each loop...

Comment: (Your `i` variable isn't helping you, though; you don't need to keep track of how many numbers the user has entered.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution

```js
function getMaxMin(){
let min, max=0;
while(true){
let input = parseInt(prompt("Podaj liczbę"));

if(input > max)
  max = input; 
if(!min || (input > 0 && input < min))
  min = input;
  
if(input == 0)
 return `Max = ${max}, Min = ${min}`;
}
}

console.log(getMaxMin())
```